# How do I locate a binary installed by one of my NPM package's dependencies so I can execute it?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an NPM package which depends on [`node-pg-migrate`](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-pg-migrate). From inside my package, I need to execute `node-pg-migrate`'s binary `pg-migrate`. I'm running node 0.12.13.

If the app I've installed my package in doesn't also depend on `node-pg-migrate`, this is trivial. The dependency is installed in a `node_modules` directory inside my package.

```
- node_modules
| - my-package
  | - node_modules
    | - node-pg-migrate
```

Here's what I would do in that case

```
exec('./node_modules/node-pg-migrate/bin/pg-migrate up', 
  function(error, stdout, stderr) { 
    // do something
  }
);
```

However, if the app I'm installing my package to *also* depends on `node-pg-migrate`, it will instead be installed in the app's `node_modules` directory alongside my package.

```
- node_modules
| - my-package
| - node-pg-migrate
```

I've thought about first checking my package's `node_modules` for `pg-migrate` and backing out one level if it isn't there, but that breaks down if my package is an inner dependency. Then, I might have to try going out one more level.

```
- node_modules
| - node-pg-migrate?
| - some-package
  | - node_modules
    | - node-pg-migrate?
    | - my-package
      | - node_modules
        | - node-pg-migrate?
```

How can I find the location of the `pg-migrate` binary and run it no matter where it falls in the dependency tree?

Answer (score 1):

```
const binDir = execFileSync('npm', ['bin']).toString().trim();

exec(binDir + ' pg-migrate up', 
  function(error, stdout, stderr) { 
    // do something
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're executing the `pg-migrate` binary from the command line, it's recommended that you install it globally

From the [npm-folders documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders):

> - Local install (default): puts stuff in ./node_modules of the current package root.
> - Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is installed.
> - Install it locally if you're going to require() it.
> - Install it globally if you're going to run it on the command line.
> - If you need both, then install it in both places, or use npm link.

With a global installation you would not need to bother where the package was installed and would be able to execute the migrate command in this manner:

```
exec('pg-migrate up', 
  ...
);
```

Comment: I can't install it globally as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

npm installs links to the various executables within node_modules in the `.bin` directory, so you don't need to go look for them in specific sub-directory.

So to get to the path you need, you can simply do this:

```
const myExePath = __dirname + '/node_modules/.bin/my-exe';
```